# How to emit side effect using new state directly after updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, side-effects

I have some code like this:

```js
const [_channel, ably] = useChannel(channelName, msg => {
    if (msg.type) === type1 {
        setStateVariable(prev => new_from_prev(prev));

        // Need the updated state for this
        if (condition(stateVariable)) {
        // This line attempts to send a socket message 
        sendMessage(/* someData */);
        }

    }
})
```

`useChannel` is a wrapper around `useEffect` with dependency array `[channelName]`; you can see the source code here: https://github.com/ably-labs/react-hooks/blob/main/src/hooks/useChannel.ts

I am not able to access the updated state this way because `setStateVariable` does the state update asynchronously. This does not work with refs either for the same reason. I am aware that I can use the callback to `setStateVariable`, however there are several problems with this. First, it violates seperation of concerns and is clearly an anti-pattern. Second, in React Strict Mode, `setStateVariable` will run twice, sending my socket message twice, which I don't want. The only solution I can think of is putting the code that needs to access the updated state into a `setTimeout` with an arbitrary timeout length. I have tried this and it works. However, this is obviously a hack and not reliable. There must be a better way to do this. Any help?

Comment: A **not-recommended** approach - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync

Comment: Isn't useEffect the thing to use when you want to do something after a variable changes?

Comment: @vighnesh153 using flushSync solves it! Thank you!